# why does the process return -1?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Running the following code:

```
int main()
{
    double hour[3];
    double charge[3];

    double sum_hour = 0;
    double sum_charge = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the hours for car No. "<<i<<": ";
        cin>>hour [i];

        if (hour [i] <= 3.0)
            {charge [i] = 2.00;}
        if (hour [i] > 3.0 && hour [i] < 24)
            {charge [i] = 2.00 + (ceil(charge [i] -3))*0.5;}
        if (hour [i] == 24.0)
            {charge [i] = 10.00;}

        sum_hour  = sum_hour + hour [i];
        sum_charge = sum_charge + charge [i];
    }

    cout<<"Car"<<setw(10)<<"Hours"<<setw(10)<<"Charge"<<endl;


}
```

I receive the following message after the ***for loop*** has been executed and the code does not run the ***cout*** after the loop:

```
Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF) execution time...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loop `for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)` array indexing should start from `0`. Change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Your array index goes out of bounds when `i is 3` here `cin>>hour [i];`, its undefined behavior.

To add here, do not do floating point comparisons:

```
if (hour [i] <= 3.0)//
```

Although this is not related to your original question, read [Why doesn't my floating-point comparison work?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html)